# Force stop app using accessibility service Android?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am using accessibility service for reading top package. But now I need to stop app and stop it's all running services through accessibility. 
I have been searching on same found clean master doing same. 
Please suggest how can I do same?

Comment: The APIs do not support this.

Comment: But clean master is doing same

Comment: The parts that do so are not related to the accessibility APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using accessibility service you can force stop application.Ref below code

```
    public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
       //TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED == 32
        if (AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED == event
                .getEventType()) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();

            if (nodeInfo == null) {
                return;
            }

            List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo
                    .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.settings:id/left_button");
        //We can find button using button name or button id
            for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
            }

            list = nodeInfo
                    .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("android:id/button1");
            for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
   }
```

Open Setting screen click application which u want to force stop from installed application.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#event-details

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to call this function? What should I send as the **AccessibilityEvent event** parameter?